# Wondering if WHILE LOOP can be used

Tags: sql, while-loop

I have a table that has

```
ITEM_LST
--------
MOD_END
LOW_END
MED_END
HIGH_END
...
JUST_OLD
```

I use the following query & replace the next one on the list:

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.db_MAIN
      SELECT LOW_END, COUNT(*) AS CNT
      FROM dbo.todays_db
      WHERE LOW_END > ''
      GROUP BY LOW_END
      ORDER BY LOW_END
```

Do I use some kind of loop if I want to cycle through the vals if I use something like the following?

```
    INSERT INTO @db_main
      SELECT @item_lst, COUNT(*)
      FROM @db_today
      WHERE @item_lst > ''
      GROUP BY @item_lst
      ORDER BY @item_lst
```

Comment: I think you're looking for a cursor, though I can't figure out why you want to do it this way.

Comment: Where would you do the loop, directly in SQL Server or in your code? If you're trying to do it in your code, you should mention the platform you are using.. And if you're trying to do it in SQL, consider using the While..Loop!